# Printing numbers in lexicographic order

Tags: python, interview-questions

I saw this problem posted as an interview question asked at Bloomberg:

> Given an integer N, print numbers from 1 to N in lexicographic order.
>   Restriction. One cannot use strings or characters.

Below is my solution to this problem. Can the algorithm be improved?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import traceback

def printlexnum(i, tens, number):
    lexnum = i*tens
    for j in range(lexnum,min(number+1,lexnum+tens)):
        print j
    if number>=lexnum:
        printlexnum(i, tens*10, number)
    return

try:
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        number = 0
        while number < 0:
            number = int(raw_input('please enter number >0: '))
        if number == 0:
            sys.exit(1)
    else:
        number = int(sys.argv[1])
        if number <= 0:
            print "Bad argument." + number + " must be greater than zero."
            sys.exit(1)
    for i in range(1,min(10,number+1)):
        print i
        printlexnum(i,10, number)
except ValueError, e:
    traceback.print_exc()
    print sys.argv[1], " Input not an integer"
except Exception, e:
    traceback.print_exc()
    print sys.argv[1], " Exception thrown"
finally:
    a = 1 # dummy line
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, let me point out some stylistic things first:

- Doing `traceback.print_exc()` in an except block feels somewhat odd. Either you hide the stack trace by printing your own error message—which is actually helpful to the end user—or you leave the exception as it is.
- Exceptions should be caught locally near to the code which may raise them. So having a big `try` block with that many lines is not really a good idea. Especially when you are catching *all* exceptions in the end—you are just hiding stuff that could be totally your fault.
- The `finally` is useless? If you want to do nothing in a block, then use `pass`; but in your case, you can just leave the `finally` block out.
- For exceptions your program could actually recover from, you really should do exactly that. When the user gets prompted for a number and enters something else, give him an error but let them try again.
- In regards to the previous point, you actually have some hint of letting the user try again, with the `while number < 0:`. However, if the user enters a non-number `int()` will throw a `ValueError` and the program will just exit.
- Using `sys.exit(1)` is like shutting your computer down by plugging the cable. Provide a better way to shut down your program. Use the existing exception mechanism to shut it down.
- `if number == 0: sys.exit(1)` — if you’re not accepting a zero either, why don’t you change the while loops condition to “lower *or equals* zero”?
- `printlexnum(i, 10, number)` — if the second parameter is always a 10, why have it as a parameter?
- `return` — No need to explicitely return from a function when that’s the last statement of the function and no value is specified.

Moving on to the algorithm:

- The order is not correct. For example `100` is being sorted *after* `19`, when it should be sorted after `10` (like `10` is sorted after `1`).
- The for-loop in the “main” program should really be handled by the algorithm too. There should be some high-level `printlexnum(n)` which just prints all numbers from 1 to n.

The easiest way to get a lexicographic order of numbers is when you sort their string representations because strings are always sorted lexicographically. You can actually do this in a single line:

```
print('\n'.join(sorted(map(str, range(1, number + 1)))))
```

Comment: Thank you for all the feedback. BTW, a restriction of the problem (which I have edited) is not to use strings.